# Cant run compiled file in Ubuntu

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, makefile

I have a problem I cant fix with a simple exercise my teacher assigned us.
I have this **main.c** that takes in a simple assembly function and I compile it with a make file, when I hit make run I get the following error :

> "make: execvp: ./main: invalid argument 
>  make:***
> [makefile:12:run]  Error 127"

This is my make file:

```
main: main.o asm.o
    gcc main.o asm.o -o main


main.o: main.c asm.h
    gcc -Wall -g -c  main.c -o main.o

asm.o: asm.s
    gcc -Wall -g -c asm.s -o asm.o

run: main
    ./main

clean:
    rm *.o main
```

My main.c file:

```
#include "asm.h"
int op1 = 0, op2 = 0, res = 0;
int main()
{
    printf("Valor op1:");
    scanf("%d", &op1);
    printf("Valor op2:");
    scanf("%d", &op2);
    sum();
    printf("sum = %d:0x%x\n", res, res);
    return 0;
}
```

My asm.s:

```
.section .data
.global op1
.global op2
.global res
.section .text
.global sum # void sum(void)
sum:
movl op1(%rip), %ecx #place op1 in ecx
movl op2(%rip), %eax #place op2 in eax
addl %ecx, %eax #add ecx to eax. Result is in eax
movl %eax, res(%rip) # copy the result to res
ret
```

my asm.h:

```
#ifndef ASM_H
#define ASM_H
void sum();
#endif
```

Comment: What is UBUNTO?

Comment: its a Linux distribution

Comment: Ah, that should be "Ubuntu" I'm assuming then.

Comment: oh, my bad, gon fix it

Comment: Make sure the makefile doesn't have CRLF newlines.

Comment: Nothing about CRLF newlines would cause this problem.  Nothing looks wrong here.  So, the problem must be in something you haven't shown us.  First, run `make clean` to be sure everything is clean then please cut and paste (no images) the _entire_ output of running `make run` into your question.  If you still get the problem run `file ./main` and see what it says.

Comment: I think the makefile is not the problem, when i type ./main in the console it shows "bash: ./main invalid argument"

Comment: After i type "make" i get the following files "asm.h asm.o asm.s main main.c main.o makefile"

Comment: Please read my comment above.

Comment: VirtualBox does not allow me to copy and paste the contents but after doing what u said (make clean and then make run) when i list the files i get the one i just said in the previous comment, when i type "file ./main" i get "elf 64-bit lsb shared object x86-64 version 1 (sysv) dynamically linked (...)"

Comment: RE: VirtualBox.  Yes you can.  Google "copy paste virtualbox" and find 100 explanations on how to enable that.  RE: the `file` output.  That means somehow you have created a shared library, not a program.  That's why you can't run it as a program.  However, the makefile you've shown us won't do that.  That's why I asked to see the actual compiler lines that make ran.

Comment: output when i "make clean " and then "make run"                ``````root@diogo-VirtualBox:/media/sf_partilha/ARQCP/arqcp21222dgg10/modulo2/ex01# make clean
rm *.o main
root@diogo-VirtualBox:/media/sf_partilha/ARQCP/arqcp21222dgg10/modulo2/ex01# make run
gcc -Wall -g -c  main.c -o main.o
gcc -Wall -g -c asm.s -o asm.o
gcc main.o asm.o -o main
./main
make: execvp: ./main: Invalid argument
make: *** [makefile:8: run] Error 127``````

Comment: And when i do file ./main ````root@diogo-VirtualBox:/media/sf_partilha/ARQCP/arqcp21222dgg10/modulo2/ex01# file ./main
./main: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=85650b69b25d9c8b0887d67ce13bf216f6b12b77, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
root@diogo-VirtualBox:/media/sf_partilha/ARQCP/arqcp21222dgg10/modulo2/ex01# 
 ````

Comment: Please edit your question and add the info there with proper formatting: we can't really understand command output in an unformatted comment.  However, I can see no reason here why this should generate a shared library.  Let me ask you this: have you defined a `main()` function in your `main.c`?

Comment: i will now add my main.c to the question

Comment: @MadScientist: A position-independent executable is indeed an ELF shared object.  So that part is normal, we haven't created a shared library by mistake.

Comment: Right I got confused.  In any event, I tried the example and it worked perfectly for me.  Just a note: you add `-Wall` but you aren't paying attention to its output: you should fix the warnings it generates.  However, these warnings won't cause the problem you're seeing.  I tried it both with and without the fixes for the warnings and both worked; I got a prompt `Valor op1:`  I can't explain what's going on on your system.  Maybe your VirtualBox is not a 64bit Intel VM?  But how did you get a x64 compiler on it?  If you run `uname -a` what do you see?

Comment: When i run ````uname -a```` i get    ````Linux diogo-VirtualBox 5.11.0-37-generic #41~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 09:06:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux````

Comment: Note that `void sum();` is only a declaration, not a full prototype in C.  `void sum(void);` would be more useful to tell the compiler about the (lack of) args.  Not the problem, though.  And it's pretty silly to provide a declaration for `sum()` but not `#include <stdio.h>` to silence all those warnings.

Comment: This works for me, and actually runs without faulting, producing the correct sum. 
 What does `file /bin/ls` show?  Does `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` exist on your system?  If not, your system gcc is configured wrong, not passing the right ELF interpreter path to the linker.

Comment: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 does exist on my system, how can i fix my gcc then?

Comment: my gcc --version ````gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.````